# How do I make an alternate caption for a sidecaption using the Memoir class?

Tags: captions, memoir

I have a sidecaption in a Memoir class document that is very long.  I need to create a short version of that caption for the list of figures.  I have tried

```
\begin{sidecaption}[short caption]{long caption}
```

but that doesn't work, the "short caption" just disappears.  How do I make a short caption when using Memoir's sidecaption environment?

Thanks

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) next time you have a question please make the code into something compilable as is. That makes it a lot easier for others to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I don't know what happened.  But apparently the code that I used in my question:

```
\begin{sidecaption}[short caption]{long caption}
```

does work.  I must not have compiled the code enough times.  Possibly it takes 3 times - at least with my system.  I had done it two times when I posted the question.